# Localization for autocomplete google api

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-api

I have the following javascript for autocomplete:

```
     function initialize(test) {

     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
     var options = {
         types: ['(cities)'],
         componentRestrictions: { country: test },
     };

     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

This works well returning the list of cities limited the country sent as parameter.  Now I want the autocomplete to be in a language which will be sent to the initialize function as parameter.

Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to set localization is by passing the language query string parameter when loading the api:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=ar&region=EG"></script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

I don't think there is any way of changing the language after the script has been loaded. You could experiment with reloading the script multiple times, but that sounds messy.

If the initialize method is only ran once, then of course you can load the api there by doing something like this:

```
function initialize(test, language) {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=' + language;

  tag.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: test },
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  };

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
}
```